# TeamCity 4 and VisualSVN Server 1.6

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, visualsvn-server

Windows Server 2008 / IIS 7...

I am trying to setup and CI environment using TeamCity 4.  So far so good, VisualSVN Server / Subversion repository is all set, TeamCity is monitoring it, and firing off the build.  I can use the TeamCity Webapp via http:localhost:8080 with no problem.  My issue is that I can't access the TeamCity webapp remotely from my development machine.  I feel like this is problem with the Apache / Tomcat configs, but don't even know where to begin.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed TeamCity 3.2.x on a Windows 2008 server and didn't run into any problems hitting it remotely, but you may want to check the firewall to see if it's open on port 8080. Windows Firewall > Inbound Rules > sort by port, and see if you have a rule defined for local port of 8080. If not, add it.

IIS Manager might be worth looking into too...  (Start > type IIS Manager) And look at the site settings for TeamCity

It's also possible that if IIS is running properly, you'll be able to hit the machine locally on port 80, just to confirm general connectivity.